# Handle textview state when fragment orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have in my fragment layout an textview with default visibility state = "GONE";
In my fragment class i add some information to textview and show it. My fragment have setretaininstance = true for cursorLoader saving.
But when my orientation changes my textview always hide. I think it because:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
    tvNowUsedFiltres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
```

It's changes state to "gone". But i cant save my instance state, because bundle always returns null with setretaininstance = true.
How can i save my text view state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setRetainInstance() does not work for widgets, because widgets are wired to the Activity (not the Fragment).

So, all you need to do is put a member boolean value in the Fragment class, and in onCreateView(), you reset the visibility parameter of that textview after getting it:

```
tvNowUsedFiltres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);

if (myNewBoolean) {
    tvNowUsedFiltres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```